# Obtain krb ticket for another user

Tags: active-directory, kerberos

I have a system account in my domain (`DOM\sys`) and it has access to service `cifs/server@DOM`. I want to obtain a ticket for this service using my own account (`DOM\user`). In other words I **need sudo-like mechanism for kerberos** - to obtain `sys`'es ticket without using his password. My flow would be:

1. obtain TGT for `user`
2. using this TGT obtain ticket to `cifs/server@DOM` for `sys`
3. now `user` can talk to `server` on behalf of `sys`

I searched for delegation / impersonation in kerberos, and found [something](http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/feature/Advanced-Kerberos-topics-Delegation-of-authentication), but it seems it isn't what I need (it "forwards" the identity proof, but still requires `sys` to provide password)

It looks like [ksu](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.5/krb5-1.5/doc/krb5-user/ksu.html) is similar to what I need, but it works only for access to local account ([here](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.5/krb5-1.5/doc/krb5-user/Granting-Access-to-Your-Account.html#Granting%20Access%20to%20Your%20Account), second bullet)

Comment: Mimikatz.... ;)

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JimB To obtain ticket for `sys` using existing ticket for `user`. Just like sudo does on local systems.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Just log in to the computer and ksu to the user you need to be...

Comment: @jmp242 The point is I need what ksu describes as "network permissions" - a ticket for another service. It's not granted by ksu